# Why did anyone invent the concepts of acids and bases?

Tags: acid-base, history-of-chemistry, teaching-lab

I am home-schooling my son in first-year Chemistry, and I am struggling to teach Acids and Bases in a rewarding way.

I am not new to Chemistry.  I went to grad school in Physics and I even taught High School Chemistry for four years.  I admit, I am suspicious of the way Chemistry is taught in school today and I think it needs radical revamping.  It's either too much like stamp collecting (memorizing a bunch of terms and rules) or esoteric (obsessing about significant figures in 8th grade seems misplaced) or else just a bunch of unit conversions (Stoichiometry) without focusing on bigger glorious ideas.

I have read a dozen textbook treatments of acids and bases.  I can follow the expanding theories from Arrhenius through Lewis.  I can do all the calculations with no problem.

What mystifies me is:  Why do Chemists care so much about Acids and Bases?

Every treatment starts with Arrhenius studying dissolving ionic compounds in water and noticing that the resulting solution conducts electricity.  I appreciate that needs an explanation, but seeing charged particles floating in water seems good enough.  No need to invent "acids" and "bases" just for that.

Then, someone discovered that litmus paper and other indicator compounds will turn different colors in the presence of certain chemicals.

Maybe scientists realized that the same explanations for what makes water solutions conductors could also explain why these indicators change to different colors, and that was enough connection to warrant these new terms "acid" and "base"?   And this is important enough to spend three chapters of a Chemistry textbook explaining?

Do professional chemists use the concept of Acids and Bases in their daily work?  If so, how?

I know this is an unfocused question, but I hope I am conveying the type of answer that would be helpful to me.  "Acids and Bases are not just a historical artifact, like phlogiston.  They really are very important to understand in modern Chemistry because ...."

Comment: If I told you that a reaction yields one product at pH = 4 and another at pH = 8 - and that one of those products can kill you and the other can treat, say, high blood pressure - would the significance of acid/base chemistry be apparent?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt For that matter, our blood pH buffers are pretty helpful.

Comment: @EdV - True! Drinking water. Aquatic life. Precipitation/dissolution reactions everywhere. It's hard to argue it's NOT important!

Comment: Concept of acids and bases is one of most useful and most used concepts of everyday life of professional chemists.

Comment: And not only for chemists. It has direct application from geology  to biology. In a sense, it is like asking a physicist if quantum mechanics is anything useful, or if it was invented just to torture students. :-)

Comment: @Poutnik Fortunately, that question cannot be asked at physics SE because it would be closed as opinion-based. But between being asked and being quickly closed by a mod, it would get three or more upvoted answers. ;-)

Comment: I don't mean this to be rude, but I find it hard to believe that someone who claims to have taught chemistry for 4 years - and who claims a graduate-level education in physics - would ask this question. Perhaps a better question is why people bother with classical mechanics, since the concept is provably incorrect and only useful in cases where an approximate answer (as opposed to the exact, quantum mechanical one) can suffice.

Comment: Do professional chemists use the concept of Acids and Bases in their daily work?   Yes, absolutely. Consideration of solution pH at various stages of a reaction is crucial. At what pH does a compound ionise is hugely important for considering whether it will dissolve, interact with another compound etc

Comment: Check [Newest 'ph' Questions - Homebrewing Stack Exchange](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ph) for examples of why pH is important, even to non-chemists.

Comment: I am sympathetic to this question. Particularly at the beginning stages, the sciences are often introduced as a set of rules to be followed and terms to be memorized, with too little emphasis on the conceptual beauty that underlies it—getting students to understand why this is interesting. I think part of the problem is that it is challenging to teach both. The mechanics and terms do need to covered, and it is challegning to find underlying concepts that can be taught to beginning students in a meaningful and understandable way. Note also that intro physics has the same problem as intro....

Comment: ...chemistry. High school phys. is mostly focused on the basic mechanics, and makes no significant mention of coarse-graining, or back-of-the envelope calculations, nor does it communicate ideas like this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1dgrvlWML4  Focusing on your question:  The acid/base dichotomy is important to chemistry, because H+ and OH- are not merely electrolytes, they are oppositely-charged electrolytes; it's important in the same way the metals/non-metals dichotomy is. Indeed, acids are typically an H bonded to a non-metal, and bases are typically an OH bonded to a metal.

Answer (score 2):

The words "acid" and "base" have both a historical origin.

The word "acid" is coming from the latin root "acies" which means "prickly". Its derivate "acidus" is an adjective used for describing a prickly, or hot, or sour liquid, because it pricks the tongue when drinking it. Another derivate is "acetum", latin name of vinegar, because vinegar is the first acidic liquid, the first known liquid pricking the tongue when drinking it.

The word "base" has another origin, which is more recent, but not so easy to explain. It needs a long explanation. In the Middle Age, it was known that acids can be destroyed (= neutralized) by adding soda, ashes or chalk. Soda ($\ce{Na2CO3}$) was obtained in Egyptian oasis. Ashes contains impure sodium and potassium carbonates, and chalk contains $\ce{CaCO3}$, but these data were unknown of course. Some alchemists called these strange substances "antacid". We will see that this name was never popular. The only fact that was accepted by all alchemists was that the reaction acid + antacid produces a new substance, a solid substance, which was called a "salt", because the sea salt was soon recognized to be also the result of an acid ($\ce{HCl}$) reacting on soda ($\ce{Na2CO3})$.

When heating a (solid) salt to a rather high temperature, it gets decomposed into two parts : nearly half of the stuff quits the solid phase as a gas (new word, coming from "ghost", created by van Helmont, b. 1577). Surprisingly enough, these vapors, when cooled, can be condensed and usually produce an acid !! And the remaining stuff, when cold, could have been described as "residue". But it was more informative to call it "base", because it stays in the lower part of the heated flask and refuses to pass into gas phase. Generally speaking, a "base" is the lower part of an object, or of a mountain. In these old times, a base is (or was) the part of the stuff that stay in the lower part of the hot container. Today, we know that this basic residue is made of oxides or carbonates. But even in the Middle Age, it was soon discovered that these bases were similar to the antacids that react with acids. So the word "antacid" was replaced by the word "base". The following "equations" could have been written .

```
        Acid + Base -> Solid salt (+ water + sometimes a gas)

        Salt (+ heat) -> Base(solid) + Acid(gas)
```

Although sea salt does not decompose this way, an important proportion of salts can be decomposed at high temperature according to this last equation, specially when the salt crystallizes with some crystallization water, like $\ce{ Na2SO3·7H2O}$, or $\ce{ Ca(NO3)2·4H2O}$, or $\ce{ Al2(SO4)3·12H2O}$. Examples : $$\ce{ Na2SO3·7H2O -> 2 NaOH(s) + SO2(g) + 6 H2O(g)}$$    followed at low temperature by : $\ce{SO2(g) + H2O(l) -> H2SO3(l)}$  $$\ce{ 2Ca(NO3)2·4H2O -> 2 CaO(s) + 4 NO2(g) + O2(g) + 4 H2O(g)}$$  followed at low temperature by : $\ce{4 NO2(g) + 2 H2O(l) + O2(g) -> 4 HNO3(l) }$ $$\ce{Al2(SO4)3·12H2O -> Al2O3(s) + 3 SO3(g) + 12 H2O(g)}$$followed at low temperature by : $\ce{SO3(g) + H2O(l) -> H2SO4(l)}$

The obtained residual base can be an oxide or a hydroxyde. It did not matter. And the acid may be partially decomposed. These facts were considered as secondary in these old times, where chemistry was not yet a science.

Today the words "acid" and "base" have a quite different meaning, of course. But it is interesting to know that these two names have a rather intuitive origin

Comment: " vinegar is the first acidic liquid, the first known liquid pricking the tongue when drinking it." Not at all, and that would be just a start...

Comment: So what is the first liquid pricking the tongue ?

Comment: Most under ripe fruit juice seems reasonable.

Comment: Acid and vinegar are nearly the same word in latin. So vinegar is the first known acidic solution. Furthermore, the English word "vinegar" is coming from the French word "vinaigre" which describes a wine (French "vin") which has become "aigre"; and "aigre" is a synonym of "acid" in French. The French word "aigre" is also coming from the latin origin "acies" which means "pricking".

Answer (score -2):

Thanks SO much for all the effort spent here!

@Maurice I loved learning the historical origins of "acid" and "base".  It will certainly enrich my teaching.

If I understand correctly, it's not so much acids/bases that are crucial on their own, but acids/bases are a stepping stone to pH, and, for whatever reason, pH is a vital consideration in lots of biological processes.

Here's my attempt to coalesce the helpful comments into an ideal (to me, at least) intro textbook section on acids and bases:

> Knowing whether a substance is a metal or a non-metal gives you lots of predictive power to guess how it will behave.  Is this substance a good conductor of electricity and heat?  Is it malleable?  What's the melting point?  All these questions can generally be answered simply by knowing whether it's a metal or non-metal.
>
> When discussing solutions, another useful classification is "acid" or "base" or neither.  This lets you predict whether it conducts electricity, whether it tastes sour or bitter, and whether it feels slippery.  This list of predictions is clearly less important than those concerning metallic nature, but there is one consequence of the acid/base distinction that's, literally, a matter of life or death:
>
> In Biology, there's a property called pH, which is intimately related to the acid/base character of a solution.  Biological processes are extremely sensitive to the pH of the surrounding solutions, and even small differences in the pH lead to wildly different outcomes in the underlying chemical reactions.
>
> So, Chemists (and lots of other scientists) have learned to pay careful attention to pH, and to understand pH, you first need to understand acids and bases.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Acid and base chemistry is a broad area, and pH is simply one way of characterizing acids and bases in liquid solutions. But there are also solid acids (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_catalysis) and gas-phase acids.  More broadly, you overly trivialize acids and bases.  They each have a rich chemistry associated with them, and are both critically important in many areas, including environmental chemistry, geochemistry, and modern industrial chemistry.   There's far more to them than sour vs. bitter, etc.

Comment: And pH itself is much more complicated when you look at the behavior of real acids and bases, e.g., if you look at a titration curve of a weak triprotic acid (an acid that can give off three H+'s):  https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Demos_Techniques_and_Experiments/General_Lab_Techniques/Titration/Titration_Of_A_Weak_Polyprotic_Acid
Separately, you might find this article useful:  https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/RP/C4RP00125G

Comment: I suggest you add this as an update to your question, reflecting your current understanding. There is a lot that is flawed in it btw. I recommend reading more Q&As on this site, and in particular the definitions of pH, acid, base etc. Also, you may find the history of science and mathematics SE site useful for this type of question, since you seek an explanation of how terms such as pH etc arose. Maurice's answer is also useful from that perspective.